# Options Menu does not appear when EditText is selected - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-optionsmenu

I have a layout with a listview and an EditText. I ve created a menu with some options.

The problem is: When the Textview is focused, the native menu button doesnt work (This only happens for Samsung Smartphones) !

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to be far more descriptive for anyone to help you. I highly doubt this is 'all' Samsung phones. Do you mean 2.2, 2.3, 4.0, 4.1? Is this an Actionbar menu button, an on screen navigation button, etc. A code sample wouldn't hurt either as that is typically much more descriptive than words.

Comment: @tencent , Theres really no code that can help anyone understand the question. Basically the Menu Button (the one most smartphones have) just does not work on samsung devices when the edittext is focused. Ive tried on Samsung galaxy ace, S2 and S3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with EditText.  I used setOnKeyListener() on the Edit Text.  The EditText would get the focus as soon as the Activity started and it was trashing the menu key action so onCreateOptionsMenu() was not being called.

Adding

```
if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ){
  return false;
}
```

on the EditText OnKeyListener.onKey() methodfixed the problem.